# put a validation function to all objects with specific attribute in jquery and use the value:true\false

Tags: jquery

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("[mandatory]").rules("add", {required: true});
            $("form").validate();
        })
        </script>
    </head>
    <blink>
        <body>
            <form action="#">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>A simple comment form with submit validation and default messages</legend>
                    <p>
                        <label for="cname">Name</label><em>*</em>
                        <input id="cname" name="name" size="25" mandatory="true"/>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="cemail">E-Mail</label> <em>*</em>
                        <input id="cemail" name="email"  size="25" mandatory="true" />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="ccomment">Your comment</label> <em>*</em>
                        <textarea id="ccomment" name="comment" cols="22" ></textarea>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </p>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </body>
    </blink>
</html>
```

It does not work, and it said on this line:

```
var settings = $.data(element.form, 'validator').settings;
```

*****Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'settings': object is null or undefined*****

Comment: please format... nobody is going to decript this mess..

Answer (score 1):

why don'y you add, like the [documentation mention](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation), a `required` as a class to all mandatory methods?

you can either add them manually, or

```
$("[mandatory='true']").addClass("required");
```

---

**data attributes:**

`mandatory` **is not a valid attribute in the HTML world**, so I would strongly suggest that you make the use of the **[`data` attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)** and change your `mandatory` to `data-mandatory` so it will be in conformity with the HTML specs.

for such, your call will change to:

```
$("[data-mandatory='true']").addClass("required");
```

...but I still don't get why not use the `required` class name, if it's needed, just add it, if not, don't add it.

---

regarding your `settings` **error**, just stop using the demo URL and use the CDN link found in the [plugin page](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/):

```
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js
```

and here is a

> [live example](http://jsbin.com/ikepah/3/edit#javascript,html,live)

---

**P.S.** `<blink>` [is not a standard HTML element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_element).

Comment: Excellent! Great, thanks a lot!
 And how can I use the value of the attribute "mandatory" true\false?

Comment: just use exactly the string you have: `$("[mandatory='true']").addClass("required");`. Add it to my answer. P.S. it's a normal procedure to upload good questions and check a valid answer so persons that find your question can easily check the correct answer. I would suggest you, as you're new around, to read the [FAQ's](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: Thanks again, and if I want to perfect it more and change the color of the text box to red, it can be done?

Comment: **You really should read the documentation**, this answer just tells that you didn't even bother to do that, do not want to use something before you, at least the start, read the docs. You can see from the code that the error is a `label` with a class, just ad your own styles for that class: `.error { color: #B80606; }`

Comment: in your `email` field you should also use an email validation, as standard, just append `email` to the class of that `input`!

Comment: in your email field you should also use an email validation, as standard, just append email to the class of that input!
I did not understand it, you can put an example. and also I did not understand where i have to put this, I try like this: $("mandatory='true']").error({ color: "#B80606" });  It does not work

Comment: add a class of `email`: `<input id="cemail" name="email"  size="25" mandatory="true" class="email" />` so it can validate bad written email's!

Comment: you would know if you take some time to read the documentation!